# Yii Custom error field

Tags: php, html, yii

hello guys I am trying to create a custom error field for all of my models where in this field will contain all of the errors what ever the current controller/action is.. like for example in my main.php:

```
<header>
...
</header>

<div id="container">
    <div id="my_custom_error_field">
        <?php //all models error goes in here ?>
    </div>

    <div id="dynamic_content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
...
</footer>
```

my question is how will I do this?
is there a built in method that gets the current models errors??
should I create a widget for this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CActiveForm, you can use `$form->errorSummary($model);`:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'my-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>false,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <div id="my_custom_error_field">
        <?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    </div>

    # The rest of the form goes here...

    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: yes I am using CActiveForm but what I need to do is to get all of the error and display it on main.php template not on the models view..so it will be displayed on the layout dynamically.. what you are suggesting will only be displayed on a specific controller/action.. What I needed is to display this errors on a separate view specifically the "layout" which is not a part of my models view..

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the errors for a model, use [`$model->getErrors();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getErrors-detail)

```
<div id="my_custom_error_field">
    <?php 
        $errors = $model->getErrors();
        foreach($errors as $key => $error) {
            // echo out to page
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I use getErrors on main.php?

Comment: and how will I get the current model?

Comment: well I am actually dealing with the layout so it will be a mess if I pass a variable to main.php.. what is the best approach?

Comment: can I use widget? then that widget will get all the error and display on the layout? whatever the current model is?